# How to get week days during period of time in flutter

Tags: flutter, date, dart, time, days

I am creating an app that includes subscription.  Now if the customer places an order from today's date to some period of time, I have to calculate total amount (which would be different for everyday). To do that I would need the number of weekdays (like Mondays,  Tuesdays,  etc.) Within a period of time in flutter.
Would be so kind of you to answer the query.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: No, the problem is in my mind for now. But lets consider you have a start date and an end date, i need number do mondays,  Tuesdays, etc. there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More specified answer because I use a loop from the start date to the end date.

Hope this is what you need. You can access `workingDays.length` to receive a count of working days if you need just the number.

```
  final workingDays = <DateTime>[];
  final currentDate = DateTime.now();
  final orderDate = currentDate.add(Duration(days: 10));
  
  DateTime indexDate = currentDate;
  while (indexDate.difference(orderDate).inDays != 0) {
    final isWeekendDay = indexDate.weekday == DateTime.saturday || indexDate.weekday == DateTime.sunday;
    if (!isWeekendDay) {
      workingDays.add(indexDate);
    }
    
    indexDate = indexDate.add(Duration(days: 1));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider the user selected a dateTime

`DateTime userPickedDate = DateTime.now();`

create a list of DateTime

```
List<DateTime> workingDaysList = [];
```

Now if the user selects 10 days from today

```
for(var i == 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  if(userPickedDate.add(Duration(days:1)).weekday <= 5) //1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday so checking 5 for Friday
  {
    workingDaysList.add(userPickedDate.add(Duration(days:1)));
  }
}
```

userPickedDate  This list will contain all DateTime of working days

Comment: Thanks for answer, i will definitely try that out and see if it solves problem.

Comment: Cool. Please mark the answer as accepted if it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

I am able to successfully solve my problem.
firstly, I took the difference from start date and end date.

```
final difference = end.difference(start).inDays;
```

Then I declared a temp variable for the start date and some variables for days.

```
DateTime temp = start;
int monday = 0, tuesday = 0, wednesday = 0, thursday = 0, friday = 0, saturday = 0, sunday = 0;
```

Then I started loop until difference calculated.

```
for(int i = 0; i < difference; i++){
  if(temp.add(Duration(days: i)).weekday == DateTime.monday){
    monday++;
  }else if(temp.add(Duration(days: i)).weekday == DateTime.tuesday){
    tuesday++;
  }else if(temp.add(Duration(days: i)).weekday == DateTime.wednesday){
    wednesday++;
  }else if(temp.add(Duration(days: i)).weekday == DateTime.thursday){
    thursday++;
  }else if(temp.add(Duration(days: i)).weekday == DateTime.friday){
    friday++;
  }else if(temp.add(Duration(days: i)).weekday == DateTime.saturday){
    saturday++;
  }else if(temp.add(Duration(days: i)).weekday == DateTime.sunday){
    sunday++;
  }
}
print("$monday $tuesday $wednesday $thursday $friday $saturday $sunday");
```

And i have what I needed.